# mysql select alias not working

Tags: mysql, select

Im having trouble with my select statement, when run title_two and author_two are not being filled properly by the next title value. Instead they print out the same as b.title and b.author. I've tried declaring them as

```
 `B.title AS title_two`.   

  SELECT R.bookone, B.title, B.author,
     R.booktwo, B.title title_two, B.author author_two, 
    R.relation, R.relationlike, R.relationdislike 
    FROM relationships R 
    INNER JOIN books B ON R.bookone = B.bookid;
```

there are two tables

relationships which has the following - relationshipid, bookone, booktwo, relation, relationlike, relationdislike

then books which is bookid, title, author, publisher

bookone and booktwo are foreign keys referencing bookid what im trying to acheive is have it so that when a user clicks a link itll come up with every relationship that book has with other books

Comment: What will it show with `B.title AS title_two`.    ?

Comment: -1 Your question is very confusing, as can be seen by the different types of answers.

Comment: there are two tables relationships which has the following - relationshipid, bookone, booktwo, relation, relationlike, relationdislike

then books which is bookid, title, author, publisher

bookone and booktwo are foreign keys referencing bookid

what im trying to acheive is have it so that when a user clicks a link itll come up with every relationship that book has with other books, instead its just coming up with bookone's title twice

Answer (score 0):

Use Quotes while using alias

```
 SELECT R.bookone, B.title, B.author,
     R.booktwo, B.title as 'title_two', B.author as 'author_two', 
    R.relation, R.relationlike, R.relationdislike 
    FROM relationships R 
    INNER JOIN books B ON R.bookone = B.bookid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join on books one more time. Something like:

```
  SELECT R.bookone, B1.title, B1.author,
    R.booktwo, B2.title title_two, B2.author author_two, 
    R.relation, R.relationlike, R.relationdislike 
    FROM relationships R 
    INNER JOIN books B1 ON R.bookone = B1.bookid
    INNER JOIN books B2 ON R.booktwo = B2.bookid
```

Comment: when making the changes you suggested the website throws this

Unknown column 'R.bookone' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 0):

They are doing what they're supposed to do. author_two should be the same as B.author, and title_two should be the same as B.title. They are just aliases.

Also, asking for the same column twice from a single table won't get the next result in the table -- it just returns the same column twice.

Comment: is there any way where i can do what im trying to acheive? 

or should i do it as two select statements then combine them

Comment: when making the changes he suggested the website throws this Unknown column 'R.bookone' in 'on clause


any ideas?

Comment: the sql in your original question has totally changed now...?

Comment: Emil's answer is still correct though. Either there's a typo or the bookone column doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If aliasing does not work in your queries, please check if you have included

> useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true

in JDBC connection string.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33966

Answer (score -1):

The correct format is: `ColName` as `NewColName`

```
SELECT R.bookone as `BookOne`
  , ...
FROM relationships R 
INNER JOIN books B ON R.bookone = B.bookid;
```

or simply ( without AS)

```
SELECT R.bookone `BookOne`
  , ...
FROM relationships R 
INNER JOIN books B ON R.bookone = B.bookid;
```

Comment: those two examples are exactly the same